# Page not found with https connection in angular project

Tags: angular, .htaccess, deployment

I have 2 angular projects. One is deployed through http and the other one is https. Both have the same problem when I'm refreshing the page. It gives me `404 Not Found` Exception. Then I saw in angular docs that you have to add an `.htaccess` file into root folder(references: [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)). It fixes my problem on my 'http' website but I still have problem on my 'https' website.

Can someone help me to fix this problem? I'm using Apache server for deployment. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use the hashbang approach?

Comment: @Jánosi-BorsosRóbert I did it to fix my problem for a while. but if there is other approach that can fix my problem without hash in my url, i will appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Well. That's all what i found too.

Answer (score 1):

Add `{Usehash: true}` in routing module. 
like

```
RouterModule.forRoot(yourRoutesHere, { useHash: true })
```

Comment: I use it right now. but, if there is other approach without hash in the url it's gonna be great

Comment: @DennyRustandi kindly comment your other approach  so, when later on any  other  person come on this question he/she get a  solution  for its problem . mark this question as solved as well,

Comment: and don't forget to upvote me as well, because this approach is also correct and helpful for others